# error storing data, {}- Redux Persist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

So I was able to successfully link up my store to my main App.js, but now I get this error about storing data. I tried to purge to see if that would do anything, and I got a similar error where it said it could not purge data stored store {}.

UPDATE:
The issue is relating to `const storage` and the redux-persist-sensitive-storage library. Still, don't know how to save the data with this library.

store.js:

```
const initialState = {};

const storage = createSensitiveStorage({
  keychainService: "myKeychain",
  sharedPreferencesName: "mySharedPrefs"
});

const config = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const middleware = [thunk];

const reducer = persistCombineReducers(config, rootReducer);

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
  );
  let persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { store, persistor }
}
```

index.js- reducers

```
export default ({
    profile: profileReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
    photoSlider,
    trip: tripReducer,
    moment: momentReducer
})
```

example of one of my reducers:

```
import {
  SET_TRIP,
  CREATE_TRIP
} from '../actions';

const initialState = {
  trip: []
}

const tripReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_TRIP:
      return {
        ...state,
        trip: action.trip
      };
    case CREATE_TRIP:
      return {
        ...state,
        trip: action.payload
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default tripReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue after running `react-native link react-native-sensitive-info`.

Solved it by running `pod install` from my `ios` directory and rebuilding the project